# Cannot send email from Windows 7

Tags: c#, windows-7, smtp

I am having a strange issue here, let me give a short overview.
I made a simple c# application which send email using google smtp in Windows 7 and its not working from my notebook. I dig into it.

"An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions". For this I deactivate my anti virus, firewalls etc. but no luck. I tried telnet smtp.gmail.com 25 and "Connecting To smtp.gmail.com...Could not open connection to the host, on port 25 connection failed"... again no luck.
I browsed almost every website dealing with this issue,but could not solve.

Nearly wasted a day on this issue. Then I have asked my colleague to telnet smtp.gmail.com 25 from his PC and it worked. And C# application also worked.
What I figured out is that I am using Windows 7 Eng Version and my colleague is using German version. Do you think this is something relevant?  This is really weird for me.

Would need your suggestions to solve this issue.

Cheers, 
Quadri

Comment: If you cannot telnet smtp.gmail.com I guess something's wrong with your internet connection. Maybe you're in some corporate network blocking smtp to all but the company's mail servers?

Comment: I'm guessing your firewall is blocking the port or somewhere there is a device through which you connect to the internet and that is blocking your call.

Answer (score 2):

I learned earlier that Windows 7 (at least the North American version) no longer ships with a built-in mail server.
At least, not all versions (I'd imagine that Server 2008 does...).

To that end, you'll have to download a mail server program which can run as a background service.

Something like hMailServer is a little overkill for what you likely need, but I don't have a whole lot of experience with various other programs.

Comment: This has nothing to do with mail server. It's actually a mail client issue!

Comment: Why did you close this question?? its not solved yet!